# Animating icon with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have animated an icon with jQUery. The first cycle is good but when it restarts for the next cycle the whole thing is sped up. Does anyone know why?

I do not know if this is the best way to do it but I don't know of any other way.
The reason it's not a gif is for alpha transparency.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/ESuGAXe/1/edit?js,output

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var plusicon = jQuery('.icon.plus');
    animateIcon(plusicon, 3000);

    function animateIcon(plusicon, duration) {
        jQuery('.sprite1', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration, function() {
            jQuery('.sprite2', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration, function() {
                jQuery('.sprite3', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration, function() {
                    animateIcon();
                });
                jQuery('.sprite1', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
            });
            jQuery('.sprite3', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
        });
        jQuery('.sprite2', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
    }
});
```

Comment: why don't you create a gif? Saves you a lot of trouble

Comment: @Stefan I need the alpha transparancy. Gif only supports full transparancy.

Comment: I can suggest you to use Spritely => http://spritely.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon completion of the final step you call the function to get it to repeat, but this time with no arguments (and hence no duration), change the inner one to this:

```
animateIcon(plusicon, duration);
```

This recursion will eventually cause an error, a cleaner way would be to wrap it in a  setInterval() like this:

```
function animateIcon(plusicon, duration) {
  jQuery('.sprite1', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration, function() {
    jQuery('.sprite2', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration, function() {
      jQuery('.sprite3', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':0}, duration);
      jQuery('.sprite1', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
    });
    jQuery('.sprite3', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
  });
  jQuery('.sprite2', plusicon).stop(true).animate({'opacity':1}, duration);
}

setInterval(function(){animateIcon(plusicon, 3000);}, 9000); /*enough time for all steps to complete*/
```

Comment: I was posting same text as Jason. Quicker than me nice one.

Comment: Dangit, I know how that feels, I'll try and add more value :)